# Unable to handle a popup

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a website, however I am unable to handle the popup. I tried using switch to frame and also dismiss alert but both didn't work. Below is the code for same. Could someone please help me.

Code:

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void Overview() throws InterruptedException {
  //driver.get(baseUrl);
    logger = extent.startTest("Overview");
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Launching the website >>> http://www.boxer.co.za/");
    driver.get("http://www.boxer.co.za/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='close-icon']")).click();

    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Click on Promotions");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.boxer.co.za/on-promotion/'][contains(.,'On Promotion')]")).click();

}
```

Comment: in which line you are getting the error and what error?

Comment: I am unable to click on the cross on the popup window :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code and lets see if it works-

```
    try{
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='close-icon']")).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: Yes this worked, but now the further elements are not clickable. I guess we need to switch back to the original frame, so how do we do that? Could you please let me know?